# BigQuery Error - Uncategorized name - When combining GA data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to combine dimensions date, country & source with sessions and unique events for event category "Downloads". Based on this data, I want to calculate the Download Conversionrate in DataStudio later on. To be honest I'm a noob in SQL. But I hope I'm thinking the right way at least.

**Trying the query below I get the following error: 
Unrecognized name: Downloads at [40:3]**

```
WITH
  ga_tables AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    trafficSource.source AS Source,
    geoNetwork.country AS Country,
    COUNT ( trafficSource.source ) AS Sessions
  FROM
    `xxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190301'
    AND '20190301'
  GROUP BY
    date,
    Source,
    Country
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    date,
    trafficSource.source AS Source,
    geoNetwork.country AS Country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS string),'-',CAST(visitId AS string),'-',CAST(date AS string),'-',ifnull(hits.eventInfo.eventLabel,
          'null'))) AS Downloads
  FROM
    `xxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190301'
    AND '20190301'
    AND hits.type = 'EVENT'
    AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Downloads'
  GROUP BY
    date,
    Source,
    Country )
SELECT
  date,
  Country,
  Source,
  Downloads,
  Sessions
FROM
  ga_tables
ORDER BY
  Sessions ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your with statement, the fourth column in the first select statement is named Sessions, while the fourth column in the statement it's unioned with is called Downloads. Due to the nature of UNION ALL, the final output column will be called Sessions, so it does not exist when you are querying it. If you want Sessions and Downloads to be separate columns, make the query look something like this:

```
 WITH
  ga_tables AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    trafficSource.source AS Source,
    geoNetwork.country AS Country,
    COUNT ( trafficSource.source ) AS Sessions,
    NULL AS Downloads
  FROM
    `xxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190301'
    AND '20190301'
  GROUP BY
    date,
    Source,
    Country
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    date,
    trafficSource.source AS Source,
    geoNetwork.country AS Country,
    NULL AS Sessions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS string),'-',CAST(visitId AS string),'-',CAST(date AS string),'-',ifnull(hits.eventInfo.eventLabel,
          'null'))) AS Downloads
  FROM
    `xxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190301'
    AND '20190301'
    AND hits.type = 'EVENT'
    AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Downloads'
  GROUP BY
    date,
    Source,
    Country )
```

Edit: Given what it looks like you want to do with the table though, you might want to rewrite ga_tables to be something like this instead:

```
WITH
ga_tables AS (SELECT
  date,
  trafficSource.source AS Source,
  geoNetwork.country AS Country,
  MAX(Sessions) AS Sessions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS string),'-',CAST(visitId AS string),'-',CAST(date AS string),'-',ifnull(hits.eventInfo.eventLabel,
        'null'))) AS Downloads
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(trafficSource.source) OVER (PARTITION BY date, Source, Country) AS Sessions
  FROM
    `xxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`),
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190301'
  AND '20190301'
  AND hits.type = 'EVENT'
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Downloads'
GROUP BY
  date,
  Source,
  Country)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Comment: One additional question. Is there maybe a more efficient way doing this i.e. with JOIN() ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, with a union you're essentially appending a table to the end of another regardless of the content, but a join puts the tables next to each other. If you are doing a join that wasn't a cross join, you would need to choose a key on which to match the rest of the contents of the two respective tables. Joins can end up being a lot slower than UNION and aren't necessarily interchangeable in nature.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful.